# Rvest is scraping something, but not what is on the website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to scrape statistics from a webpage that has data from the Little League World Series. The site only has one table on it, so I assume the .[[1]] should be okay. It does scrape some data, but none of these names are names of the athletes on this specific team and variables are off as well. Here's my code

```
library(rvest)
West <- read_html("https://gc.com/t/summer-2018/west-5b3ad51e396a0500018e8513/stats")
West %>%
html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_table
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
    Batting AB R H RBI[?]
1 J Stevens  4 2 1      -
2 S Roberts  3 0 1      -
3 C Stevens  1 1 0      -
4   R Meier  4 1 2      -
```

None of those are names of the players on the team from the west. The columns are out of order or wrong too. I've looked around but can't find what this  is pulling from. I'm new to web scraping so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the page is likely being loaded by js or a server bases process. To scrape it you will need to use something RSelenium.

Comment: No, you do not.

Answer (score 0):

It's well past the season so the OP likely doesn't need this but mebbe enough examples will finally cause questions like this to not be asked.

That site *does* use javascript via XHR request to async load content but we definitely do not need to introduce heavyweight dependencies like Selenium into the  picture to solve most problems like this.

You can see the URL it async XHR loads here (start practicing using browser Developer Tools):

[image]

Now, that URL is generated dynamically as well (yay convoluted, suboptimal web app design). So, we need to get clever. I used [`curlconverter`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) to see the format of that URL (it's nasty as you can see below). But, it's nasty *and* uniform. So, you should be able to post any team stats URL (it *has to be just like the one you showed*) as the parameter and get back lovely javascript. Here's the lightly commented function:

```
get_team_stats <- function(team_stats_url) {

  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(httr, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE)
    library(jsonlite, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE)
  })

  res <- httr::GET(team_stats_url) # to prime cookies
  httr::stop_for_status(res) # and also validate the team URL

  # extract the team id
  team_id <- gsub("^[[:alpha:]]+\\-", "", strsplit(team_stats_url, "/")[[1]][6])

  httr::GET(
    url = sprintf("https://gc.com/stats/team/%s/", team_id), # use the team id
    query = list(
      stats_requested = "[{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"GP\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"PA\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"AB\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"H\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"1B\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"2B\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"3B\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"HR\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"RBI\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"R\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"HBP\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"ROE\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"FC\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"CI\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"BB\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"SO\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"AVG\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"OBP\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"SLG\"},{\"category\":\"offense\",\"key\":\"OPS\"}]",
      qualifying_stat = "{\"key\":\"GP\",\"category\":\"offense\"}",
      game_filter = "All"
    )
  ) -> res

  httr::stop_for_status(res) # warn if anything goes wrong

  jsonlite::fromJSON(
    httr::content(res, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
  )

}
```

Let's give it a go:

```
team_stats <- get_team_stats("https://gc.com/t/summer-2018/west-5b3ad51e396a0500018e8513/stats")

str(team_stats, 1)
## List of 3
##  $ glossary:'data.frame': 20 obs. of  5 variables:
##  $ players :'data.frame': 14 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ totals  :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
```